# Difference between ValidatorForm and DynaValidatorForm

Tags: struts

What is the difference between ValidatorForm and DynaValidatorForm ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the difference between ValidatorForm and DynaValidatorForm?

The answer to this is in fact the difference between ActionForm and DynaActionForm.

In Struts, everybody knows the [ActionForm](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.7/api/org/apache/struts/action/ActionForm.html) class (so I'm not gonna talk about it). But not everybody knows (or understands the purpose of - me included) the [DynaActionForm](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.7/api/org/apache/struts/action/DynaActionForm.html).

The idea behind DynaActionForms is that instead of creating a form class for each HTML form, you instead configure one (you declare their properties, types and defaults in the struts-config.xml file). It was supposed to be "Dyna"mic you know... but turned out to be some thing that nobody understood or used and presented some major disadvantages:

- they act sort of like a Map so it has the same problems of maps, like retrieving data from it, you know, as an Object which you then have to cast. So you have casts everywhere;
- compiler no longer notifies you when you screw something up like a name of a property for example, so compile errors turn into runtime errors;
- the things are not really dynamic since you still have to restart the server after you "reconfigured" the properties in the struts-config.xml file (or else modifications won't be picked up);
- code completion does not work on DynaActionForms, type safety sucks (we are not taking generics here) and there are other nuisances that I can't remember right now.

Well... the idea is that, from a Struts point of view, you have two main types of forms to deal with: ActionForm and DynaActionForm (even if the DynaActionForm is in fact a subclass of ActionForm).

But you also have the [validator plugin](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.4/userGuide/dev_validator.html) where you place your validation rules in an external file and make them pick up by your action forms. You hook up the validator plugin by using a child of ActionForm: the ValidatorForm. And since you have two types of forms you must hook up the validator plugin for the DynaActionForms also: enter the DynaValidatorForm.

In conclusion, the ValidatorForm and DynaValidatorForm are the same thing but applied to different "beasts".